# Vue reactivity issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I am trying to concat 2 arrays of arrays, but there is no effect because of async fetching one of them.

```
this.subcategories = [...this.subcategories, ...[ this.$store.getters['categories/subcategoriesOfCurrent'] ]];
```

Getter above is being set after some ms (server response) so when this assignment is triggered, getter is empty. When state is set (server responded), array 'subcategories' should be updated but it is not (but getter is). How to solve it?

More code:

getter:

```
subcategoriesOfCurrent: (state: CategoriesState, getters: any) => {
        return (getters.current && getters.current.subcategoryIds) ?
            getters.current.subcategoryIds.map((id: string) => getters.all[id]) : [];
    }
```

actions:

```
setCategory: ({ commit, dispatch }: ActionArgs, categoryId: string) => {
        commit('setCategory', categoryId); //sets current category Id
        dispatch('fetchSubcategories', categoryId); //fetching from server which commits updateCategorySubcategories
    },



fetchSubcategories: ({ dispatch, commit }: ActionArgs, parentId: string): void => {
            HttpService.getInstance().get(`/categories?parent_id=${parentId}`).subscribe(
                result => {
                    commit('updateCategories', result.data);
                    commit('updateCategorySubcategories', { parentId, categories: result.data });
                }
            );
        },
```

mutation which updates subcategoryIds:

```
updateCategorySubcategories: (state: CategoriesState, { parentId, categories }: { parentId: string; categories: Category[] }): void => {
        Vue.set(state.categories[state.currentCategoryId], 'subcategoryIds', categories.map(category => category.id));
    },
```

Comment: are you saying that `this.$store.getters['categories/subcategoriesOfCurrent']` is asynchronous?

Comment: @JaromandaX I added more code

Comment: I don't know vue ... but ... when you say *`after some ms (server response)`* - are you saying that `this.$store.getters['categories/subcategoriesOfCurrent']` is asynchronous?

Answer (score 1):

Create a computed for the subcategories:

```
computed: {
    subcategories() {
        return [...this.subcategories, ...[ this.$store.getters['categories/subcategoriesOfCurrent'] ]];
    }
}
```

since computed props are reactive, it will change the result each time the getter changes